# How to pass Ref or Ptr of a templated class with non-type Parameters

Tags: c++, templates

Say I have this class template with two non-type parameters:

```c++
template<uint16_t tValA, uint8_t tValB> class TClass
    {
         ...
    };
```

If possible. How can I pass either a reference or pointer to a function, such as:

```
TClass<300,4> Instance1;    
TClass<340,5> Instance2;

aFunction(Instance2);

void aFunction(TClass<uint16_t,uint8_t>& _Instance)
{
    _Instance.DoSomething();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With a template function:

```
template <uint16_t N1,uint8_t N2>
void aFunction(TClass<N1, N2>& instance)
{
    instance.DoSomething();
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to pass a reference to another template parameter as well?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. `template <uint16_t N1,uint8_t N2, typename T>
void aFunction(TClass<N1, N2>&, T&) ` ?

Answer (score 2):

`TClass<300,4>` and `TClass<340,5>` are distinct types without a common base class (`TClass` does not count), so they can't be passed to the same function, unless you template it as well:

```
template <uint16_t tValA, uint8_t tValB>
void aFunction(TClass<tValA, tValB>& _Instance)
{
    _Instance.DoSomething();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't because TClass<300,4> and TClass<340,5> are different types.

But if you have common parent class, like,

```
class ParentClass
{
public:
    virtual void DoSomething();
};

template<uint16_t tValA, uint8_t tValB>
class TClass : public ParentClass
{
    //...
};
```

Then you can have argument with that parent class.

```
void aFunction(ParentClass& _Instance)
{
    _Instance.DoSomething();
}
```